# Javascript object method does not update variable

Tags: javascript

```
var myUser = (function () {
    var username = "",
    var isConnected = false;
    return {
        setUsername: function (n) {
            username = n;
        },
        setConn: function (connStatus) {
            isConnected = connStatus;
        },
        user: username,
        isCon: isConnected
    };
}());
```

When I call

```
myUser.setUsername("user123");
```

username variable does not get updated.

Any advice?

Comment: Probably just a typo, but missing a `;` on the `var username = ""` line... Have you tried `this.username = n` instead, so you're setting the object's own username member, and not some random variable whose name happens to be the same?

Comment: You mean like it [was defined to begin with](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/e4Haf/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to use myUser.user to refer the updated username value.
However, if that's the case, it doesn't work. setUsername updates username variable, but myUser.user only points to username's initial value, which is "". It won't points to the updated username value

to fix the problem, you can change

```
user: username,
```

to

```
user: function() {
    return username;
},
```

Comment: Exactly. To the asker: please note that the connection getter and setter have to be reworked as well, according to the same logic. Also, `setConn` is currently introducing a global variable `isConn` (typo?)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's a typo, I changed the variable names when copying pasting here.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better case to use prototype model:

```
function User(prop) {
  prop = prop || {};
  this.username = prop.username || '';
  this.isConnected = prop.isConnected || false;
}
User.prototype = {
  setUser: function(uname) { this.username = uname; },
  setConn: function(status) { this.isConnected = status; }
};

var myUser = new User();
myUser.setUser('user1234');
// OR
var myUser = new User({ username: 'user1234' });

console.log(myUser.username); //=> 'user1234'
```

Comment: what does prop = prop || {} do?

Comment: it just makes sure that `prop` is not undefined. It means _if there's no `prop` then use an empty object_

Answer (score 0):

```
    ....
    },
    user: username,
    isCon: isConnected
```

`user: username` forces the `username` to be evaluated, which returns "". This is more easy to figure out what happend

```
   var obj = {
        log: console.log("printed when init")
   }
```